# Would a non-round eye, one that doesn't look like a circle from the outside, be possible and functional?

Tags: xenobiology, aliens

Could an eye that is triangular-looking from the outside have any sort of advantage over a round eye?
I'm interested in any nonconventional eye form discourse so anything on the subject is appreciated.

Comment: How do you mean triangular. Normal eyes (eg. mammalian, cephalopod) are three dimensional and spheroid. Are the eyes you're asking about flat? Could you add more details including worldbuilding context, else this is pure biology and off-topic as not-about-worldbuilding. In cross-section, insect eyes are made of clusters of triangular tubes (i.e. cones in three dimensions.). Please clarify what you're asking.

Comment: Couldn't you use a spheroidal eyeball, and make the opening a different shape? That would make the eyes appear for example triangular, but the actual eyeball would still be round, and able to rotate.

Comment: @AngryMuppet I tried editing the question a bit and i might do it again when i wake up, sorry ig i was a bit too tired too ask it better.don't think they would be flat but they wouldn't move ig. I'll give context tomorrow if you really wanna know but i got my answer already

Comment: A digital camera has a light detection array that is generally rectangular.  (It might be a collection of rectangles arranged in a circle in some cases.)  The lens of course is still round for the same reason that biological eyes are.

Comment: Many arthropods have their compound eyes arranged is less spherical ways, so maybe that might help you in your quest.

Comment: Do you mean the full eye (which is vaguely spherical (3D) rather than a circle (2D)), or the eye opening (i.e. the space between eyelids, which has a complex shape very different from a circle in most people, with shapes varying a lot), or the iris (the coloured part of the eye, which is indeed circular in humans, not sure this is universal), or the pupil (the black part in the center of the iris, which is circular in humans, but not in all animals, like cats), or...?

Comment: Could you be more specific? If you're interested in "any nonconventional eye form" how, specifically, could anything triangular-looking from the outside matter? Can you say how triangular is better than rectangular - square or oblong - dodecahedral or anything else?

In any case if you want triangular - or any other - eyes, why not just write them?

Could you re-visit this after watching, for example, the much-maligned Mortal Engines movie of 2018?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## Eye shape only determines eye mobility, not eye function

There are two questions here, I will answer the title question: *Would a non-round eye be possible or functional?*

From the real world, there are many advantages to eyes of different shapes. While I think the question mostly concerns the outside “eyeball” shape, we can’t really talk about that until we talk about the most important parts of the eye, which actually let light in and focus it on the “film”, or retina. Those parts are the pupil and the lens.

### Pupil

The pupil is what allows light to enter the eye, and pupils definitely do NOT have to be round. When we manufacture camera lenses, they are usually round, but not always. This is because we have very simple film manufacturing processes that make an even, flat, and uniform surface for the light to be recorded on. Our film (or digital recording chip, as the case may be), is not intended for one specialized purpose. We want it to be versatile, and allow the customer to simply reproduce whatever comes into the camera as accurately as possible.

An eye doesn’t have this limitation. An animal is not creating fine art, or making a sales brochure. An animal is surviving, and its eye is a functional tool that will process the light around it in the way that help it survive best. An animal will have an eye that gives it an advantage in the environment it needs to live and find food in.

“Advantage” is a relative word, there is no single feature that makes something an advantage. Let’s start with something simple.

Eyelids are an advantage to animals living in a dry desert where dust and arid conditions dry eyes out, but in a pond they serve no purpose at all and only get in the way. So fish don’t have eyelids, and that is an advantage. Camels do have eyelids, and that is an advantage. This is why the question is a bit of a puzzle. How can anyone answer if a square or triangle eye is an “advantage” without knowing the world the creature lives in? You see, it is the same as asking if an eyelid is an advantage. Yes it is, and no it isn’t. It depends on what the creature’s world looks like.

On earth, there are very many different environments and animals have come up with many different pupil schemes to create an advantage in their worlds. The most extreme example I can think of is the W-shaped pupil of the cuttlefish.[image: Pupil shaped like a W in cuttlefish]

We often make the mistake of thinking an eye is a camera that reproduces the outside world for our brains. That is one function, of course, but not all of it. The pupil shape of this eye allows the cuttlefish to see its environment clearly nearly 360 degrees around itself, so it can swim and hunt what is in front of it without loosing track of what is behind it (something is always hunting you on the ocean!) The dip in the pupil is a sort of light hood which prevents too much surface light from getting in.

But what sort of picture would this pupil and lens make? How can the cuttlefish make sense of the warped image it gets? The answer is two fold: First, it doesn’t need to “make sense” of the light that comes in because the cuttlefish eye is linked directly to its most valuable weapon: its skin. The cuttlefish has [the most amazing camouflage on earth](https://youtu.be/4IDCpz7bY6I) as it can change its colors, skin texture, and body shape to resemble spiny coral, flat sand, a mottled rock, or almost anything it is near. Even though the cuttlefish itself is color blind, its body will match the colors of a rusty pipe, deep violet coral, or green sea grass. New research has found that the cuttlefish doesn’t need to “understand” that the grass below it is green, it simply needs to stop thinking about what it is seeing altogether and its skin will mimic the spectrum of light coming into its weird light-bending pupil. The picture that gets to its brain is probably more simple. It sees the food, knows where the food it, and eats the food. It sees the shark, knows where the shark is, and hides from the shark.

So an eye is not only designed to “see” and create realistic pictures for the brain. Cameras do this, but eyes do much more specialized functions.

So why are so many eyeballs shaped like a ball? Because a ball can rotate and spin in a socket. This way, the area of the eye which has the best focus can be pointed at the thing it wants to watch without moving its whole head or body.

### Lens

The lens needs to deliver the light where it belongs. If the animal wants an accurate picture, then the lens needs to focus it clearly like an eagle. If the eye needs to filter out light spectra to copy its environment quickly and accurately, like the cuttlefish, then the lens should act like a prism and provide the spectrum information needed. Why would a cuttlefish care about fine details in a coral bed, when all it needs is the basic pattern and color information? The eye doesn’t give the cuttlefish useless information to process. It gives the skin texture and spectrum information, which helps it stay alive by quickly and unconsciously copying its surroundings.

### There are situations where a simple round eye is less advantageous than a specialized eye.

If an eye can focus without moving around, like a Google Earth 360 camera, then it only needs to be “round” if the retina is a simple surface. A retina can be shaped in any way needed to make a triangle eye work. Your story needs to create the world that makes it an advantage.

Comment: You provided detailed argument about pupil and lens, but then just jumped into a conclusion about the entire eyeball. "Your story needs to create" sounds to me like "please answer your own question".

Comment: I thought the answer was quite simple in the summary. If it doesn’t need to move, it doesn’t need to be round. The pupil can be any shape as well depending on the world they create. I Thought including the “why” would be a useful guide.

Comment: This is all very interesting. Yes, yes. THis helped me a lot. Thanks Vogon

Answer (score 8):

I'm not quite sure what you mean about "from the outside," but many avian eyes are not spherical. How dramatically non-spherical they are varies with species, but owl eyes are shaped like cocktail shakers, with a large domed cornea transitioning to a tapered cylinder. This maximizes the amount of light gathering capacity while still fitting into the physical constraints of the owl's skull size.

This may not answer your question if by "from the outside" you mean outside the creature's body, since owl eyes do appear round to an outside observer.

Comment: By "outside" I meant the part you see, like, at least that part to not be round-looking. I didn't knew the thing about the birds thing, or that eyeballs could even be as asymmetrical, so thanks for your answer too

Answer (score 7):

To the limit of my understanding, the ideal eye is always round because the lens effect which allows eyes to focus on objects requires that incoming light be evenly dispersed in all directions within the eye - so a triangular eye would needlessly warp incoming images which would then require additional brain power to correct - but then I'm told our eyes interpret the world upside-down and our brains switch it around for us, so so much for efficiency.

If you willing to go for compound eyes (where you don't have one eye with all the light receptors inside but rather thousands of mini-eyes with a single light receptor each) then I guess you could arrange your compound eye receptors in triangles. As long as you have two compound eyes you should still get depth perception and whatnot. /shrug

If you looking for personal sensors which interpret the world and don't specifically need to be eyes however, you can go with any shaped plate you want. You can have light, sound or even electromagnetic sensors which appear as scales, plates or dots on the skin - and those can be whatever shape and size you want.

Comment: thank you for your answer it clarified a lot

Comment: The same amount of "wiring" is necessary to connect an inverted image to the necessary brain cells as a non-inverted image. The only difference is which nerves connect to where.  There is no inefficiency resulting from the image being inverted on the retina (as happens with any pinhole camera). There would be considerable inefficiency in designing an eye that somehow reversed the image optically first so that it would not be inverted.

Answer (score 6):

I am an example of a being with a non round eye.

My eyeball is roughly spherical, but the question asked about the eye, which mightnot be the same thing as the eyeball.

Fom the outside the visible part of my eye looks sort of like the space between two interesting segments of arc.  With my eyes open the upper arc is usually much more curved that the lower arc.

I suggest that you go look at your face in a mirror.  I expect that the part of your eye visible to other people will have a similar shape to what I have described as the shape of my visible eye.  In fact, if you claim that the shape of your eye that is visible on the outside doesn't look like the shape I described for my eye, you should enclose a photograph if you want me to believe you.

I note that animals on earth usually have spheroidal eyeballs, but the shapes of their visible eye parts differs a bit.  Thus I can imagine an alian animal or person with a spheroidal eyeball and a rectangular or triangular or star shaped visible part of the eye.

In fact, a rather small modification of the upper eyelids of humans could make the visible parts of their eyes seem like flattened triangles, with the upper eyelid having two straight lines meeting at a point in the center.

A similar modification to the bottom eyelid would make the shape of the visible part of the eye a lozenge.

Answer (score 0):

Eye shape can be an indicator if an animal is [predator or prey](https://physicsworld.com/a/eye-shape-reveals-whether-animal-is-predator-or-prey/).  There is a huge amount of variety in how animals see. Cats having vertical pupils sheep having horizontal slits. Compound eyes. Even scallops have an set of photosensitive cells that lined up in row.  The ways the different retinas work can be different too, for example being more sensitive to motion than stationary objects for some animals like some frogs. Some animals are sensitive to different types of polarization or can see more colors than humans.

So I think for a story you could have eyes be pretty divergent from a human eye, but the question might be what is the evolutionary advantage.

Comment: This is a difference in the shape of the *pupil*, not the whole eye.  Cats and sheep and frogs and basically everything else that has what we would generally recognize as eyes will still have eyes that are roughly spherical in shape.  Even compound eyes like those of insects or arachnids are a collection of lots of little spheres when you look closely enough at them.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman They aren't collections of spheres at all, they're collections of domes, which may or may not have spherical curvature, capping truncated hexagonal pyramids.

Comment: That is because a sphere is a good shape to minimize volume and from an energy perspective is also efficient. But it is not a requirement to have a functioning eye.

Comment: @LoganR.Kearsley Hemispheres, close enough.  They can have other non-spherical curvature, but this reduces the effectiveness of the lens.  In some cases, it's not the lens itself that's spherical but the arrangement of the multiple lenses in a compound eye.  In one way or another though, most eyes take advantage of the focusing effect of a spherical surface.

Comment: But you don’t have to have a lens to have a functioning eye. Scallops for example have a tiled mirror structure with an off axis focus that has been compared to a segmented telescope. https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/science.aam9506

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Spherical lenses are actually pretty crap, if you want to get a clear image. They don't produce a single focal point.

Comment: Raptor eyes are also not even *close* to spherical--and they don't need to be, because they can't rotate in the head! They are circular and domed on the front surface, but... weird-shaped on the inside. (https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/journeynorth.org/images/graphics/d-e/eagle_eagleeye.GIF)

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine tucking an additional triangular-ish eye between e.g. three circular structures such as fingers or tentacles, the advantage being additional sensor coverage.